# I need to measure traffic from root domain to subdomain as Refferal - GA4

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain

I need help with the following case. My client has a website where the catalog and product informations is on the main domain https://fixed.zone from the product cards links to the eshop which is on the subdomain https://obchod.fixed.zone

I need the person who clicks through from the root domain to the eshop to be a referral in GA4. It now appears as Direct.

Can anyone advise me how to achieve this? The GA4 code is only on the eshop. It is not on the catalog page. I didn't set up the analytics on the main domain but someone else did. However, I can also intervene in the website on the root domain

I tried to google the solution but it seems to be kind of rare set up

Answer (score 0):

Referral attribution is something you typically don't touch. It's something Google comes up with on its own. If this dimension doesn't do the trick, you just use a different dimension, like the actual referrer, or a segment where you select sessions that have both hostnames.

Still, there is a way to trick GA. A few ways, actually. For example, you could have logic in GTM that would run on subdomain that would check user's document.referrer on every hit before sending pageview. Once the referrer is from the TLD, you override the referrer dimension in the call and replace the TLD in it to something else, that way those hits will look like they came from a different TLD and will be treated as referral traffic.

Or you could issue an event every time a user navigates to the subdomain, so you could just look at those events.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.  Managing a GTM container and GA4 property for a subdomain that is separate from main domain.  By default in GA4, it appears as though the main domain traffic is lumped in with direct traffic rather than a referral.  We need isolated referral data from main domain to subdomain in GA4.  Lumping the traffic into direct will not work for us.  The UA property for the same subdomain lists the traffic from the main domain as a referral.

I created a GTM GA4 event tag for traffic tracking.
parameter name: referrer_URL
value: {{HTTP Referrer variable with component full URL}}
trigger: Page View - trigger fires on: {{HTTP Referrer variable with component full URL}} does not contain "my.subdomain" (to exclude self-referrals)
created custom dimensions in GA4 for new parameter "referrer_URL" so it will be visible in reports

After approx 24hrs my new custom dimension started showing up in reports.

In GA4 reports->Acquisition->Traffic acquisition click the "+" next to first column header of "session default channel group" and select custom->"your.custom.dimension" (or search for your custom dimension).  Default channel groups should be broken down further into your custom dimension urls.